# grep just uniq data with latest time-stamp

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, uniq

I have a file test.txt

```
A 2018-11-28 10:04:59.286
A 2018-11-28 10:07:59.286
B 2018-11-28 10:04:58.993
B 2018-11-28 10:06:58.993
C 2018-11-28 10:04:55.714
C 2018-11-28 10:04:59.714
```

I would like to pick just uniq data per each (A,B,C) based on latest timestamp

The resulet should be:

```
A 2018-11-28 10:07:59.286
B 2018-11-28 10:06:58.993
C 2018-11-28 10:04:59.714
```

I used sort+uniq command but I can not find the right solution for me.

Thanks

Comment: please click [edit] and add the sort+uniq command you tried as it is expected here that you add your efforts to question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `sort/awk`

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2r file | awk '!a[$1]++'

A 2018-11-28 10:07:59.286
B 2018-11-28 10:06:58.993
C 2018-11-28 10:04:59.714
```

reverse sort from second field on, pipe to `awk` to pick the first record per key (first field).

Comment: Hi thanks for help.

It works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `sort` and `uniq`. You can reorder the result with `sort` if you'd like.

```
$ sort -r file | uniq -w 1
C 2018-11-28 10:04:59.714
B 2018-11-28 10:06:58.993
A 2018-11-28 10:07:59.286
```

`man uniq`:

```
 -w, --check-chars=N
              compare no more than N characters in lines
```

Comment: Hi thanks for help.

It works like a charm :)